# Why are strange symbols equal to numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, glob

```
symbol1=႔

if [[ $symbol1 == [4-5] ]]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

output:
yes

Not the only such symbol that matches a digit in bash.

Comment: What ASCII characters does that decode to? Also, post your locale settings (easiest way to get them all is to run the `locale` command). Also, _exactly_ which version of bash is this?

Comment: To answer the first question, you can run `printf "႔" | xxd`. Maybe compare its output to `printf "45" | xxd` to help you answer your question yourself.

Comment: And to check the running shell version, use `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`. (Alternatives like `bash --version` can be wrong sometimes). If that doesn't output anything, your shell isn't actually bash.

Comment: And you are not even using a regex. Regex is enabled with `=~`.

Comment: fwiw, I get the same result (test succeeds => 'yes') with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`, but get no result (test fails => no output) with `LANG=` (unset `LANG`); same results for `bash v 4.4.12` (`locale v 3.4.6` - cygwin) and `bash v 5.1.16` (`locale v 2.35` - ubuntu)

Comment: It would be nice to see what's inside those character classes, because very close to 100% of the internet just repeats what the classes contain without anybody checking, even less in every programming language separately. Even in official docs I found that it would not match or match more what was written down to match. I found out about that by testing every possible character.

Comment: It has nothing to do with utf8 encoding matching ascii encoding or something like that. I think @CharlesDuffy is expecting (and that was also my first idea, tbh) that utf8 encoding of that ႔ would have a 0x34 somewhere (which is not directly possible, btw, since utf-8 encoding never uses bytes < 0x80, except for single bytes chars. So only `4` has a 0x34 in its utf-8 encoding), or that would have been the case in some other strange encoding used by OP, or that unicode value itself would end in 0x34 (that could have been possible).

Comment: But ႔ has is unicode character 0x1094, encoded in utf-8 as sequence 0xe1 0x82 0x94. So, no 0x34 anywhere. Simply, 0x10** characters are those of Shan language (burmese — obviously I've known that only for 5 minutes, since I've look unicode table up). And more specifically 0x109* chars are digits. 0x1094 being digit "four" in that language

Comment: Btw sed's 0-9 also matches similarly such symbols.

Answer (score 4):

This is a `4` in [Shan alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shan_alphabet)

So it matches number 4 because it is number 4, with another writting.

Edit: some addition after Philippe's questions.

`man bash` says that when we use `==` with a `[a-b]` range, then range is checked according to collate (`LC_COLLATE`) rules. So it is a matter of how those chars are sorted under your locale rules. When a simple `a == b` comparison is just a plain `==`. And ႔ is not == to 4.

So let's play with sort to check how that would be sorted

```
printf "3\n5\n႗\n႖\n႔\n4\n႔\n4\n႓\6\n7\n" | sort
```

Gives

```
3
႓
4
4
႔
႔
5
႖
7
႗
```

So, burmese digit ႓ (3) gets sorted after 3 but before 4. Burmese digit ႔ after 4 but before 5. ႖ is 6, is obviously after 5 and before 7. ႗ (7) after 7.

So `x == [y-z]` still means `x` is between `y` and `z` included. But according to this collating.

So ႔ is indeed in any range starting with 3, ႓, 4 or ႔ (limiting myself in this example to the characters I've used for my example. Otherwise, of course, that range could also start with 0, 1, 2, and some ponctuation chars that are before 0), and ending with ႔, 5, ႖, 7 or ႗. But not in range `[3-4]`: ႔ is after 4, and not equal to ႔

So, said otherwise, considering the characters
`0 ႐ 1 ႑ 2 ႒ 3 ႓ 4 ႔ 5 ႕ 6 ႖ 7 ႗ 8 ႘ 9 ႙`
you can pick any combination of 3 characters x, y and z in this set of 20 characters, and the rule
`[[ x == [y-z] ]]`
*is true iff x is equal or after y in my list, and x is equal or before z in my list*
always apply

Will we complicated things even further?
Take another set of digits. The Arabic ones (I mean, the one that the people writing in Arabic use. Our 0,1,2,3,... are called "Arabic digits" because we took them from those arabic digits. Nevertheless, we alter them since, so they are not identical, even if we can see some similarities):
۰   ۱   ۲   ۳   ۴   ۵   ۶   ۷   ۸   ۹
So 4 is ۴ (unicode 0x06f4)

(In fact there are two sets of digits in arabic unicode page. They are very similar. But for 4, that can also be written ٤, unicode 0x0664)

Note that `[[ ۴ == [4-5] ]]` is true, but `[[ ۴ == [3-4] ]]` isn't. For the same reason. ۴ is 4, and gets sorted after 4 but before 5.

But what is `[[ ۴ == [4-႔] ]]` and `[[ ۴ == [႔-5] ]]` are?
Well, the first is true, and the second is false.

Because arabic digits, are sorted after equivalent ascii digits, but before equivalent burmese digits.

I see no clear rules about why, but I surmise one easily: unicode code for those digits (ascii, arabic, burmese) are in this order. So, collation is made according to digit value first, then, in absence of other criteria, to unicode code number. I don't know if that is a rule, or just how implementation falls when all reason in sorting algorithm to swap two bytes are exhausted. But in the mean time, that is so.

We can check it with yet another 4: ༤ (Tibetan one). Code 0x0F24.

It should be after 4 (0x34) after ٤ (0x664) after ۴ (0x6f4) but before ႔ (0x1094), and of course, before 5.
Let's check

```
[[ ༤ == [4-٤] ]] && echo between 4 and ٤. Should be no
[[ ༤ == [٤-۴] ]] && echo between ٤ and ۴. should be no
[[ ༤ == [۴-႔] ]] && echo between ۴ and ႔. should be yes
[[ ༤ == [႔-5] ]] && echo between ႔ and 5. Should be no
```

Try with other `4` if you wish: ๔, ໔, ፬, ៴, ៤, ᪄, ᪔, ᭔, ...

Comment: How can we explain that `[[ $symbol1 == [4-5] ]]` gives `true`, but `[[ $symbol1 == *4* ]]` gives false ?

Comment: `[[ $symbol1 == [3-4] ]] also gives false.

Comment: Answer to first question is easy, and can be found in `bash` manual: when `==` is used with a range, then it is matched according to `LC_COLLATE` rules. And in such rules ႔ must be sorted after 4 and before 5.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` is not involved when just checking for equality.

Comment: Answer to second question is related. ႔ is not equal to 4. It is just something that is sorted just after 4 and before anything else. So it is in range `[4-5]`, but not in range `[3-4]` (while `4` itself is in both range `[3-4]` and `[4-5]`). You can check that, likewise, `4` is in range `[4-႔]` but not in range `[႔-5]`

Comment: Curiously, comparing to `[[:digit:]]` doesn't match: `[[ ႔ == [[:digit:]] ]]` is false. I wonder if it would, using a Burmese locale (which I don't have)?

Comment: @BenjaminW. `LC_ALL=my_MM.utf8 bash -c "[[ ႔ == [[:digit:]] ]]"` is false as well.